# Testing posting to multiple pages

Tags: testing, facebook-page

We're working on a system that will people to post to multiple pages (think Hootsuite).

We obviously want to be able to test this before launch, and to do so will need to test across multiple pages. The message in most cases will be slightly different, but it'll be useful to test for any rate limits we're unaware of.

I can obviously go and create X Facebook pages for test purposes, but is there any way to create a 'test page', like you can create test accounts? Nothing in the documentation that I've seen suggests this, but wanted to check.

Many thanks,
Kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test accounts can create pages. These should disappear with the test account.